# Resolving error 404 when connecting to an API

Tags: mysql, angular

I am creating a web application with angular 6, I would like to connect it to a database.
So I used wamp: mysql and PHP and this is what my api returns at this address http://localhost/tests/getAll.php:

[image]

I'm trying to connect to it from my app :

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

private log(log: string){
    console.info(log);
}

private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

        return of(result as T);
    };
}

getlisteUsers(): user{
    console.info('yess2')
    let data;
     this.http.get("http://localhost/tests/getAll.php").pipe(
        tap(_=> this.log(`chargement de la liste réussit`)),
        catchError(this.handleError(`getlisteMotAApprendre`, [])))
    .subscribe(res => data = res);
    return data
}
```

When I call this function 
I have this error :
[image]

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: this appears to have nothing to do with mySQL. It's more like an AJAX, HTTP, JavaScript question. Please tag your question appropriately to get the best change of relevant help. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, it seems the error is quite simple, the app cannot find a file called getAll.php in that folder. Check it definitely exists at the location on your local disk where that URL maps to.

Comment: When I go to this URL on my browser I find the json file

Comment: is your Angular code also running on `http://localhost` (and definitely not on some other port number) on the same computer?

Comment: My angular application runs on localhost: 3000 / and my api on localhost:80/

Comment: It's possible you have a CORS problem, then. Is your PHP set up to accept CORS requests and return the appropriate headers?

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: Ok well that's just a header to stay the data is JSON. it's nothing do with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: So what i can do ??

Comment: You'd have make your PHP return the necessary headers as described in the documentation (and in many many previous posts on StackOverflow and elsewhere). P.S. It _might_ not be CORS, because a 404 error isn't really a normal symptom of that, but from the environment you've described I can't think what else would cause the browser to think it can't reach the URL. Are you sure there are no other errors in your console at this time? What about in your Network tab - does it also show a 404 in there for the same URL? Have you tried specifying `localhost:80` explicitly?

Comment: I tried everything you proposed to me but I still have the same error

Comment: In that case there is something wrong with your environment which is related to information you haven't given us. And I'm not really sure what it would be. It's hard for me to help any further, sorry. Perhaps someone else will know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like angular is unable to reach this file
Try to specify your local server xampp or wamp port in api url and then try.
like this.

```
getlisteUsers(): user{
    console.info('yess2')
    let data;
     this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/tests/getAll.php").pipe(
        tap(_=> this.log(`chargement de la liste réussit`)),
        catchError(this.handleError(`getlisteMotAApprendre`, [])))
    .subscribe(res => data = res);
    return data
}
```

Comment: I specified the wamp port (80) but I still have the same error